# MPMediaPickerController in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, picker

I am rebuilding one of my apps in SwiftUI but I have hit a snag.

My question is this..  My app is an AudioVisual Test Generator and currently has the ability to select a test song from the user device's music library, and set that song as the test song for the application.   Other tests include Left Speaker, Right Speaker, etc, but this feature allows a user to select their own custom Test Song from their device's library, (or it defaults to a default test song.)

My app is currently written in Swift and uses the MPMediaPickerController to select the song and it works just fine.  However, I am having a real hard time making the music library picker controller work with my SwiftUI rebuild. Anyone know a solid way to access the user's Music Library in SwiftUI?

I keep getting stuck with objects not conforming to class protocol 'NSObjectProtocol' which leads me to believe there is a more SwiftUI-y way of doing it?  Or perhaps I can use SwiftUI for most of my app but transition to a UIView for the song selection?

Here's some code that doesn't work yet and isn's pretty.. I was just throwing everything I could at the problem and planning on refactoring if I got it to work.

//probably importing a few more things than i need.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import MediaPlayer



class SongPickerController: UIViewControllerRepresentable, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = context.coordinator
        return imagePickerController
    }
    
    func makePickerController(context: Context) -> MPMediaPickerController {

        var picker = MPMediaPickerController()
        picker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .anyAudio)
        //picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
        picker.showsCloudItems = false
        picker.prompt = NSLocalizedString(Texts.pickerDetail, comment: Texts.pickerComment)
        return picker
    }
           
        func songSelectButtonClicked () {
           picker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .anyAudio)
            picker?.delegate = self
            picker?.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
           picker?.showsCloudItems = false
           picker?.prompt = NSLocalizedString(Texts.pickerDetail, comment: Texts.pickerComment)

            self.present(picker!, animated: false, completion: nil)
    
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MPMediaPickerController, context: Context) {
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        var parent: SongPickerController
        
        init(_ imagePickerController: SongPickerController) {
            self.parent = imagePickerController
        }
        
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}}}}

struct SongUIView: UIViewController, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {

    var picker: MPMediaPickerController?

    func songSelectButtonClicked () {

        picker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .anyAudio)
        picker?.delegate = self
        picker?.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
        picker?.showsCloudItems = false
        picker?.prompt = NSLocalizedString(Texts.pickerDetail, comment: Texts.pickerComment)

        self.present(picker!, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }


    func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController,
        didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection){
            let selectedSong = mediaItemCollection.items
            if (selectedSong.count) > 0 {
                let songItem = selectedSong[0]
                let songURL = songItem.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL)
                let saveString = "\(songURL!)"
                let saveTitle = "\(songItem.title!) by \(songItem.artist!)"
                saveDefaultSong(saveString as NSString, title: saveTitle as NSString)
                mediaPicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                ///selectSongButton.setTitle("Custom song assigned!", for: UIControl.State())

            }
    }

    func mediaPickerDidCancel(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController) {
        mediaPicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func saveDefaultSong (_ name: NSString, title: NSString) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(name, forKey: "Default Song")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(title, forKey: "Default Song Title")

    }
}
```

Comment: This is great.  I just got it all working yesterday and ended up using a solution VERY similar to yours.  I ended up passing back the MPMediaItemCollection for playback in a      MPMusicPlayerApplicationController.applicationQueuePlayer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is based almost entirely on Dave's post of Jul 28th. That previous code did not yet have a way of selecting the song and passing it to a View. In the example below it is passing the selected song to an @EnvironmentObject, but it could just as easily be used with a @Binding as Dave suggests.

```
import SwiftUI
import MediaPlayer

struct MusicPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var player: AudioPlayer

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {
    
        var parent: MusicPicker

        init(_ parent: MusicPicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    
        func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
                    
            let selectedSong = mediaItemCollection.items
        
            if (selectedSong.count) > 0 {
                let songItem = selectedSong[0]
                parent.setSong(song: songItem)
                mediaPicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func setSong(song: MPMediaItem) {
        player.setAudioTrack(song: song)        
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MusicPicker>) -> MPMediaPickerController {
        let picker = MPMediaPickerController()
        picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MPMediaPickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MusicPicker>) {
    }

}
```

Comment: white Screen blink, can you tell me how can I solve?

Answer (score 1):

`UIViewControllerRepresentable` is SwiftUI View, so have to be a struct

```
struct SongPickerController: UIViewControllerRepresentable
```

but `UIViewController` is UIKit class, so inherited entity have to be a class

```
class SongUIView: UIViewController
```

Comment: Yes, I went down that path.  Sorry, this must be from some reverted code.  I'll go down that path again and let you know where I am getting stuck.

Comment: Okay..  Looks like with enough coffee, enough google, and a boost of confidence from you I have succeeded in presenting the Music Library.  I will post my code to do so below, but thanks for nudging me in the right direction.   I am still having issues when making a selection (I suspect due to an Apple Music token issue) but I am back on track again! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After user Asperi nudged me in the right direction I wanted to share my final code to present the music library in SwiftUI.  Here is the first part...

```
import SwiftUI
import MediaPlayer

//MUSIC PICKER.. WORKING
struct MusicPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var song: Song?

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {
        var parent: MusicPicker

        init(_ parent: MusicPicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MusicPicker>) -> MPMediaPickerController {
        let picker = MPMediaPickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MPMediaPickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MusicPicker>) {

    }
}
```

And then to call it in my SwiftUI View I declare a couple @State vars

```
@State private var song: Song?
@State private var showingSongPicker = false
```

And use this button to present the Media Picker

```
    Button(action: {
        self.showingSongPicker = true
    }
    ){
        Text("Edit Test Song")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showingSongPicker) {
        MusicPicker(song: self.$song)
    }
```

Note: I am still working through some Apple Music Token issues, and the selection of a new test song isn't working yet. But the part of presenting the music picker was what this question was about and that is working now.